# PRF from hash function?

Tags: hash, pseudo-random-function

Let $G=\langle g \rangle$ be a cyclic group of prime order $Q$. Let $H_1:\{0,1\}^*\to G$ be a hash function. Is the following a family of PRF for $s \in \mathbb{Z}_Q^*$?

$$f_s(x)=(H_1(x))^s$$

Or equivalently, let $H_2:\{0,1\}^*\to \mathbb{Z}^*_Q$ be a hash function,

$$f_s(x)=(g^{H_2(x)})^s$$

Intuitively it is in ROM, but can somebody prove it?

Comment: I assume H is public, then if logarithm is easy to compute, it is not PRF. This is because one can pick $x$ and compute $H(x)$, then given $f_s(x)$, find $s$. After having $s$, $f_s(x)$ can be easily distinguished from a random string.

Comment: @ChangyuDong I should say assuming discrete log is hard.

Comment: There are still problems e.g. $H(x)$ may not be a generator of the group, what is the distribution of $s$. I think you need to define the problem more formally.

Comment: @ChangyuDong added more details.

Comment: If you assume $H_1$ and $H_2$ are random oracles and $s$ is chosen uniformly random from $Z_Q$, then yes $f_s(x)$ is pseudorandom.

Comment: Once it has been chosen, is $s$ public?

Answer (score 3):

The first construction is a well-known PRF in the random oracle model, with security from DDH. I can't find a good reference right now where this construction is explicitly framed as a PRF, but I will update if I find it.

> Edit: this is the PRF that is implicit in private set intersection protocols dating back to:
>
> Catherine Meadows. A More Efficient Cryptographic Matchmaking Protocol for Use in the Absence of a Continuously Available Third Party. In IEEE Symposium on Security and Privacy. 1986
>
> Bernardo A. Huberman, Matt Franklin, and Tad Hogg. Enhancing Privacy and Trust in Electronic Communities. In ACM Conference on Electronic Commerce. 1999

The second construction is insecure. If I know $f_s(x)$, then I can raise this value to the $H_2(y)/H_2(x)$ power (inversion is mod $Q$) and this tells me $f_s(y)$. So I can easily distinguish $f_s(y)$ from random.

BTW, in the random oracle model, $f_s(x) = H(s,x)$ is a PRF, as is $f_s(x) = g^{H(s,x)}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think, under DDH one can prove this to be a weaker form of PRF.
If one considers $H_1$ to be a composition of two hash functions $H_1'$ and $H_1''$ with appropriate domain and range, then one can prove the construction to be PRF under DDH if both $H_1$' and $H_1''$ are modeled as RO.
I am not sure if the construction verbatim gives a PRF.